# How do I make a tablix span multiple pages even when KeepTogether = 'False'?

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I currently have a report in SSRS that has a large blank area on the first page if I print it or export to PDF.  There is no blank space when I view it in html.  The report has two main sections, first a rectangle then a tablix.  There is a blank space after the rectangle on the first page that pushes the tablix to the second page because it is trying to keep the tablix together.  I have KeepTogether = 'False' on the tablix.  My desired result is for the tablix data to be partially on page 1 and to spill over into page 2 so that there is no blank space.  I know that there may not be an exact solution to this problem but if someone could point me in the right direction I would be much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution I did was to add a new row to the top of the tablix and then to move the rectangle and it's contents into that row.  I guess that it counts the tablix as one chunk of content that cannot be separated and that's why all of the content in the tablix was getting pushed to a new page.